# Why do we often set the basis to be orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, change-of-basis

I found many theorems in the textbook set the basis to be orthonormal. For example, in this theorem, we let $\beta$ be an orthonormal basis. Why do we need this condition? It seems like that the equation still holds if $\beta$ is not orthonormal.

> [image: Theorem]

Comment: It is convenient. There are many arbitrary choice of basis, but by the gram Schmidt argument we may always take it orthonormal, simplifying calculations

Comment: Hm, and on inspection of your image I realise that it is not necessarily true if the basis is not orthonormal.

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for your reply. Could you explain why this is not necessarily true?

Comment: You should explain why you think the equation should hold. Step through the proof of the theorem to see why orthonormality of $\beta$ is required

Comment: @FShrike I tried to prove the theorem and found that it indeed fails to hold when the basis is not orthogonal. Thanks for your help.